# How to setup postman with grant_type=customercode

Tags: postman, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, access-token, bearer-token

My appsetting.json has value

```
{
    "BaseAddress": "https://www.test.com",
    "GrantType": "customercode",
    "AuthorizationType": "bearer",
    "ContentType": "application/json",
    "Username": "test",
    "Password": "test",
    "CustomerCode": "testcustomercode",
}
```

I am calling API to get token

https://www.test.com/Api/Token

But I am getting below error

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

Could any one help me how to setup postman if grant_type has some different keys then "password".

In backend code I am calling method

```
PostAsync([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] Model model)
```

Comment: How did you sent the request? Could you share the steps you have tried? In addition, could share the request details of `https://www.test.com/Api/Token` you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

Is it oauth2?
If yes, postman, has the best support.

[image]